# Xpath to check if nod is null or text ist empty

Tags: xml, xpath, null, isnullorempty

I tried to find a xpath pattern to check, if the node is null or the child of the node is empty. But I couldn't find a solution.

I have the following XML:

```
 <ns2:getRFSParametersRequestContent>
   <ns2:userAccountId>asdfasdf</ns2:userAccountId>
 </ns2:getRFSParametersRequestContent>
```

Now i need to check, if userAccountId is empty like . But sometimes, the node userAccoundId does not exist, in this case, I will also get the information, that it doesn't exist.

```
<ns2:getRFSParametersRequestContent>
</ns2:getRFSParametersRequestContent>
```

So that in case of missing node, or the node is empty, my xpath will match on true.
But I can always just check if node is null or if the text is null.

Is there a possibility to check both in one pattern?

Comment: Did you try `boolean(//getRFSParametersRequestContent/userAccountId[normalize-space()])` to check that `userAccountId` is present and it's not empty?

Comment: I need for our framework a statement which is true. The boolean does give me always false, when the node is null or the text is empty

Comment: Ok. In this case `not()` will give you opposite result. Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48865718/xpath-to-check-if-nod-is-null-or-text-ist-empty/48866325#48866325)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get `true` if `userAccountId` node is absent or in case it doesn't contain any text content, try

```
boolean(not(//getRFSParametersRequestContent/userAccountId[normalize-space()]))
```